# docker volume mounted after files were deleted

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When I mount local `build` directory to container `/app/build`, then excute `docker-compose up`, it will be generated a `/app/build` directory, expecting it exists on local `build` directory, but nothing on there.

If not mount, container `/app/build` directory has expected files

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to achieve? During the build step of docker compose the built package should be copied to the image. Afterwards it should be enough to start the image, without any need for mounting the volume with the built artifacts to the running container, as the files are already in the image.

Example:
[image: screenshot]

`docker compose build` only modifies the content inside the build container, which is then written as layer to the built image.

As you see, the `COPY ./package .` from the `Dockerfile` does what's expected, but only inside the container. Also the following

```
RUN bash -c 'source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install 17.1.0 \
    && npm install'
```

Does what's expected, as the `node_modules` folder is present inside the container. You can verify this also by looking at the file timestamps.

To geht your desired behavior you could do the following:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${pwd}:/app ubuntu:20.04 bash
apt update
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.0/install.sh | bash
cd /app
cp -Rv package/* .
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install 17.1.0 \
    && npm install
touch build/x
exit
dir .\build\
```

As you see in the screenshot the filesystem outside the container is modified using this approach:

[image: screenshot 2]

Summary:

- use `docker compose build` to build a project inside a container, without modifying the outside filesystem
- use `docker run -v -v ${pwd}:/app` if you want the build to modify the outside filesystem.

Comment: I expect local `build` directory exists files what container build step `npm run build` generated

Comment: @linka Updated the answer with further explanation and demo.

Comment: my understanding is when image build success, `/app/build` exists files, But then as a volume on `docker-compose.yml`, because of host build directory is empty, after excute `docker-compose up`, container `/app/build` directory actually is equal host `build`, so it is empty.   

Then, I moved `npm run build` to ENTRYPOINT, it meet expected,

Comment: Moving npm run build to ENTRYPOINT is equal in its effect to my second alternative. Your compose build creates an image with the needed development tool, at container runtime you start the build. I would recommend to build at image creation as the overall result is more predictable

Comment: Thank you, I will try it